# Retrieve List Index for all Items in a Set

Tags: python, google-app-engine, numpy

I have a really big, like huge, Dictionary (it isn't really but pretend because it is easier and not relevant) that contains the same strings over and over again. I have verified that I can store a lot more in memory if I do poor man's compression on the system and instead store INTs that correspond to the string.

```
animals = ['ape','butterfly,'cat','dog']
```

exists in a list and therefore has an index value such that `animals.index('cat')` returns `2`

This allows me to store in my object `BobsPets = set(2,3)`
rather than `Cat` and `Dog`
For the number of items the memory savings are astronomical. (Really Don't try and dissuade me that is well tested.

Currently I then convert the INTs back to Strings with a FOR loop

```
tempWordList = set()
for IntegOfIndex in TempSet:
    tempWordList.add(animals[IntegOfIndex])
return tempWordList
```

This code works. It feels "Pythonic," but it feels like there should be a better way. I am in Python 2.7 on AppEngine if that matters. It may since I wonder if Numpy has something I missed.

I have about 2.5 Million things in my object, and each has an average of 3 of these "pets" and there 7500-ish INTs that represent the pets. (no they aren't really pets)

I have considered using a Dictionary with the position instead of using Index. This doesn't seem faster, but am interested if anyone thinks it should be. (it took more memory and seemed to be the same speed or really close)

I am considering running a bunch of tests with Numpy and its array's rather than lists, but before I do, I thought I'd ask the audience and see if I would be wasting time on something that I have already reached the best solution for.

Last thing, The solution should be pickable since I do that for loading and transferring data.

Comment: A `set` contains *references*. The references are the same size whether they point to a string, an integer or back to the set itself (although this wouldn't work, as sets are mutable so cannot themselves be placed into sets, but you get the idea).

Comment: Moving the Master List to a Tuple made a much larger difference than I had anticipated.

But @jonrsharpe for brevity I didn't do the full explanation my "sets" are only talked about here as sets because I wanted to make sure it was clear that they were unique, and you wouldn't have to look up the INT for dog six times.

Moving to a Tuple for Animals, seems to have sped up that part of the operation by about 30%. That was a huge win.

Comment: If you just offer a vague description of what your code and data structures are *like*, we can't be much help.

Comment: jonrsharpe the question is specific to the speed at which you find the indexes of items in a list that is unique, and the best way to build that list.

That part doesn't require that I provide the very long code snippet that makes up the custom Class and Object that makes up the container.

Hence the very clear, "I have verified".

The parts I wasn't sure about aren't verified, like if a NUMPY array, or a Tuple, or some variation on a custom list could be faster.

A Slot, or a frozen dict... The Frozen Dict test was what lead me to Tuples, which I didn't realize being frozen lists are faster.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that since my list of strings is fixed, and I just wish the index of the string, I am building what is essentially an index array that is immutable. Which is in short a Tuple.

Moving to a Tuple rather than a list gains about 30% improvement in speed. Far more than I would have anticipated.

The bonus is largest on very large lists. It seems that each time you cross a bit threshold the bonus increases, so in sub 1024 lists their is basically no bonus and at a million there is pretty significant.

The Tuple also uses very slightly less memory for the same data.

An aside, playing with the lists of integers, you can make these significantly smaller by using a NUMPY array, but the advantage doesn't extend to pickling. The Pickles will be about 15% larger. I think this is because of the object description being stored in the pickle, but I didn't spend much time looking.

So in short the only change was to make the Animals list a Tuple. I really was hoping the answer was something more exotic.